# Generate and Decode QR Codes from PHP

Tags: java, php, barcode, qr-code, zxing

Can anyone recommend a PHP library (if one exist) that will generate and decode QR codes? This seems to do the job: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ but it is in Java. If I have to use ZXing, how do I make it work from PHP?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/khanamiryan/php-qrcode-detector-decoder) out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like [PHP QR Code](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/) will do what you want.

Comment: .... but it doesn't decode - sorry! perhaps two libs?

Comment: I've looked at this. It seems to only generate QR codes. I need to generate and decode. Suggestions?

Comment: From what I can tell, there are no PHP native apps at this stage to decode. I'd suggest looking at zxing further - a previous question mentioned a C++ implementation which you may be able to coerce into a PHP extension. Alternatively, I believe zxing has a web accessible decoder which you could use from PHP.

Comment: I can't use a web service. How do I convert C++ to a PHP library?

Comment: You wouldn't.. you'd write a php extension to use the C++ library.  A little beyond my knowledge of PHP sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to work over HTTP:

There is a web-based encoder from zxing at http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx. I don't suggest you use it directly, but since the source is available in the open-source project under `zxingorg/`, you can easily run your own. Then you can decode QR codes by POSTing the image data to the server over HTTP.

For encoding, likewise, you could just use the Google Chart Server, which has generated QR codes for a long time. Look at http://zxing.appspot.com/generator -- it will show you the image URL pointing to the chart server that makes the image. You can just use the same to grab encoded images in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Zbar at http://zbar.sourceforge.net/ can decode qr codes, and it can be compiled into at php extension with the PHP wrapper at https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zbarcode.